# Why is ''To Be'' verbs a thing even if the predicate is a verb?

Tags: verbs, present-continuous, predicate

I know that in English there can't be a sentence without a predicate. So we use these ''To Be'' verbs to make a valid sentence.
But I wonder why we use them even if the predicate is a verb?

What is the real difference between ''They eating'' and ''They are eating''?

Comment: Where have you seen "they eating"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Are eating" is the present progressive tense (third person plural) of the verb 'eat', and is also the predicate of the sentence. They: subject, are eating: predicate.

http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/present_progressive.htm

http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/predicate.htm

Comment: Thank you for your response. I might to know why just ''eating'' can't be the predicate and need the ''are'' verb.

Comment: The present present progressive tense is formed by am/is/are and the -ing form of the verb. "They eating" would be nonsense.

Comment: Note that *they eating* is "nonsense", but ***them** eating* could be a valid *noun phrase*. Compare *I don't like chocolate* and *I don't like **them eating***, for example.